# Use CSS/Jquery calc function in React Js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a situation where I need to give dynamic width to the `div` so I need to use this `divStyle = {width: calc(100% - 276px)}` in my React Js code. But doing so it gives an error that `calc is not a function`.

I know this can be achieved using Jquery but I dont want to introduce JQuery to my application. If there is any kind of workaround or hack that might solve this then please share.

code:

```
customFormat = 'hello-div'
divStyle = {width: calc(100% - 276px)}
return (
    <div className={customFormat} style={divStyle}>
      Hello World
    </div>
)
```

Comment: how are you using it in reactjs?

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: divStyle should be a string. `divStyle = '{width: calc(100% - 276px)}'`

Answer (score 76, accepted):

If you need some more specific CSS you need to put it into quotes - [react inline styles doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style)

```
<div style={{width: 'calc(100% - 276px)'}}></div>
```

In your exact case

```
customFormat = 'hello-div'
divStyle = {width: 'calc(100% - 276px)'}
return (
    <div className={customFormat} style={divStyle}>
      Hello World
    </div>
)
```

In case you need to overwrite multiple widths ([fallbacks](http://cssinjs.org/json-api?v=v9.8.7#fallbacks)) for browser compatibility

```
divStyle = {width: 'calc(100% - 276px)',
    fallbacks: [
        { width: '-moz-calc(100% - 276px)' },
        { width: '-webkit-calc(100% - 276px)' },
        { width: '-o-calc(100% - 276px)' }
]}
```

Comment: The space on both sides of the minus sign is important

Comment: I always forget the space, thanks @ShortArrow